# Why a custom action doesn't use the whole screen in the salesforce 1 web?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I've been looking to fix this issue for a while now.

I have a visualforce page and a custom action for account. I added the action in the page layout. If I go to the salesforce 1 app with the browser on the computer (https://na10.salesforce.com/one/one.app) or in the phone and use that action, the custom page is only shown in a little space at the top of the page. It doesn't happen in the native salesforce 1 app for android.

[image]

It's the same in Chrome and Firefox.

I followed the steps in chapter 12 of https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_intro_set_up_org.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce support and apparently it's an issue that will be fixed in a future release.

Update: It's scheduled for Spring 15' release.

Comment: Still not fixed. Even standard custom actions do not use the screen full estate. Really annoying, users have to click "More" to see 1 added field when there is 2/3 of screen left!

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your page code

```
 body { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

This should fix it. I've tested it - worked well in both Chrome & FF

Comment: It doesn't work. In the mobile version of Chrome it shows the icon of error. In Firefox mobile and desktop and in Chrome desktop it shows it in the same little space as before but now the scroll doesn't work.